# Migrating data from solr to elastic search

Tags: search, elasticsearch, solr

What would be the best way to migrate Solr cores to elastic search indices ?

The solr-river-plugin (https://github.com/javanna/elasticsearch-river-solr) is deprecated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a nice adhoc Python tool made with love by the nice folks at OpenSource Connections that you can use to do this:

https://github.com/o19s/solr-to-es

Simply

```
./solr-to-es solr_url elasticsearch_url elasticsearch_index doc_type
```

For instance, the command below will page through all documents on the local Solr node, named `node`, and submit them to the local Elasticsearch server in the index `my_index` with a document type of `my_type`.

```
./solr-to-es.py localhost:8983/solr/node localhost:9200 my_index my_type
```

Comment: How can I specify fields to process. I get an error for a date field which contains some garbage data.

Comment: The error is from jodatime date parser. It cannot parse the date in format: +42534-01-01T00:00:00Z. Which is obvious. But the field is not important for me currently. So I want to skip this field and import all others. Can I specify this in  --solr-query parameter ?

Comment: You can try `q=*:*&fl=-datefield` or `q=*:*&fl=field1,field2,...`

Comment: What query did you try?

Comment: python .  --solr-query '*:*&fl=id,ean,name'   'http://localhost:8983/solr/products  'http://localhost:9200' new-product product

Comment: Let me ask the developer of that library, I know him ;-)

Comment: Ok, I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/o19s/solr-to-es/pull/2) that adds the possibility to specify the fields to import from Solr. Once this gets merged, you can simply add `--solr-fields=field1,field2,field3` to specify which fields to import, otherwise all fields will get imported.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: The PR has been merged into the master branch.