# Error executing solr-to-es in Anaconda: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solrSource'

Tags: python, elasticsearch, solr, anaconda, pysolr

I am trying to run solr-to-es (https://github.com/o19s/solr-to-es) in Anaconda environment. I run the setup.py without errors, then when trying to execute "solr-to-es -h", I get "No module named 'solrSource'". I don't get this error when with a Python 2.x environment, however the requirement is Python 3.x.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527338/migrating-data-from-solr-to-elastic-search

Answer (score -1):

Hack:

```
cd solr_to_es

python \__main__.py localhost:8983/solr/select localhost:9200 es_index solr_docs
```